# Ocultar opción con radio button en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, radiobutton

```js
function option(x){
    if(x===0){
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='hidden';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='visible';
    }
    return;
}
```

```html
<p><label for="optionYes">Entregado Hoy: <input type="radio" name="optionYes" id="yes" onclick="option(0)" checked/></label></p>
            <p><label for="optionNot">No entregado: <input type="radio" name="optionNot"  id="not" onclick="option(1)"/></label></p>
            <p><label for="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate">Fecha de entrega: <input type="date" name="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate" ></label></p>
```

Tengo un problema en que se oculte la opción automáticamente y con los botones radio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero debes poner el mismo nombre en el atributo "name" de cada input de tipo radio, para que al seleccionar uno o el otro la selección cambie, segundo, si con "automáticamente" te refieres a que apenas cargue, como está seleccionado por defecto la opción "Entregado hoy", basta con que llames a tu función con el valor por defecto de dicha opción.

```js
function option(x){
    if(x===0){
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='hidden';
    }else{
        document.getElementById('deliveryDate').style.visibility='visible';
    }
    return;
}
option(0);
```

```html
<p><label for="optionYes">Entregado Hoy: <input type="radio" name="option" id="yes" onclick="option(0)" checked/></label></p>
            <p><label for="optionNot">No entregado: <input type="radio" name="option"  id="not" onclick="option(1)"/></label></p>
            <p><label for="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate">Fecha de entrega: <input type="date" name="deliveryDate" id="deliveryDate" ></label></p>
```